# Hide app name in ToolBar if SearchView overlaps it

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat, searchview

I have an app that is using the AppCompat theme and a custom Toolbar, which has the app name and a searchView. When the searchView opens on a phone-sized screen, there isn't enough room for both the textView with the app name and the opened searchView, so it expands the toolbar vertically and looks bad.

To fix this, I remove the textView with the app name when the searchView opens:

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

And brig it back when the searchView closes:

```
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
    title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return false;
    }
});
```

However, on a larger screen device, like a tablet, this is not necessary and the name just disappearing looks weird.

Is there a way to check to see if there is room for the searchView to open, and remove the app name only if necessary? I know that I can probably do this by screen size, dpi, or something like that, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to detect this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

One solution and simple one is using [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts). you can store a `boolean` value in your `values` folder name it for example `hasEnoughWidth` and set it to `false`. then another boolean value to screen size that you think it has enough width, just guess it for example minimum width of `400dp` may be good. So store a `boolean` variable with a same name in a folder `values-w400dp` and set it to `true`. then just read that `boolean` value and decide upon it. this is a common technique that is used a lot for detecting tablet or phone.